# Simple preg_replace

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I cant figure out preg_replace at all, it just looks chinese to me, anyway I just need to remove "`&page-X`" from a string if its there.

`X` being a number of course, if anyone has a link to a useful `preg_replace` tutorial for beginners that would also be handy!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually the basic syntax for regular expressions, as supported by `preg_replace` and friends, is pretty easy to learn. Think of it as a string describing a pattern with certain characters having special meaning.

In your very simple case, a possible pattern is:

```
&page-\d+
```

With `\d` meaning a digit (numeric characters 0-9) and `+` meaning: Repeat the expression right before `+` (here: `\d`) one or more times. All other characters just represent themselves.

Therefore, the pattern above matches any of the following strings:

```
&page-0
&page-665
&page-1234567890
```

Since the `preg` functions use a Perl-compatible syntax and regular expressions are denoted between slashes (`/`) in Perl, you have to surround the pattern in slashes:

```
$after = preg_replace('/&page-\d+/', '', $before);
```

Actually, you can use other characters as well:

```
$after = preg_replace('#&page-\d+#', '', $before);
```

For a full reference of supported syntax, see the [PHP manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: so what if I wanted to replace "/page-1"

Answer (score 6):

[`preg_replace`](http://docs.php.net/preg_replace) uses [Perl-Compatible Regular Expression](http://docs.php.net/pcre) for the search pattern. Try this pattern:

```
preg_replace('/&page-\d+/', '', $str)
```

See the [pattern syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
$outputstring = preg_replace('/&page-\d+/', "", $inputstring);
```

[preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/&page-\d+/', '', $string)
```

Useful information:

[Using Regular Expressions with PHP](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php)

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/regular-expressions-php