# Replace text with other text using php css using Preg_Replace

Tags: php, html, regex

**css styling**

```
<style>
.red { color: red; }
.blue { color: blue;}
</style>
```

**Code in php**

```
<?php
$string = 'I want a [red]red[/red] apple and a [blue]blue[/blue] umbrella';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/[red]/';
$patterns[1] = '/[/red]/';
$patterns[2] = '/[blue]/';
$patterns[3] = '/[/blue]/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '<span class="red">';
$replacements[1] = '</span>';
$replacements[2] = '<span class="blue">';
$replacements[3] = '</span>';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

But it does not take me value , that is, does not change effected. I tried removing the '\' but still does not work me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple preg\_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487064/simple-preg-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape special characters (`[` or `/`) in regex. Here's the working code:

```
<?php
$string = 'I want a [red]red[/red] apple and a [blue]blue[/blue] umbrella';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\[red\]/';
$patterns[1] = '/\[\/red\]/';
$patterns[2] = '/\[blue\]/';
$patterns[3] = '/\[\/blue\]/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '<span class="red">';
$replacements[1] = '</span>';
$replacements[2] = '<span class="blue">';
$replacements[3] = '</span>';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
// outputs: I want a <span class="red">red</span> apple and a <span class="blue">blue</span> umbrella
?>
```

You could even go further and write the code in a more general way (supporting more colors, that is):

```
$string = 'I want a [red]red[/red] apple and a [blue]blue[/blue] umbrella';
$regex = '/\[(red|green|blue)\]([^][]+)\[\/\1\]/i';
// provide an alternative and capture it in the first group
echo preg_replace($regex, "<span class='$1'>$2</span>", $string);
```

See an example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d956ca7d973e72cc725144952917918f3bc9c24).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the patterns should be like the following..

```
$patterns[0] = '/\[red\]/';
$patterns[1] = '/\[\/red\]/';
$patterns[2] = '/\[blue\]/';
$patterns[3] = '/\[\/blue\]/';
```